# Access VS-Team Services OAuth through Asp.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, oauth-2.0, azure-devops

I need to connect VS-Team-Services in `WebService` via `OAuth2`.
I have found a [sample solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/tree/master/dotnet/aspnet) in the official web site but I am not able to modify it to use it in our web services code.
Because it is asking for the permission `Accept or Deny` when requesting for access token.
I need it to automatically grant access for the token without the permission page.

This is my previous working code without OAuth. I need this code to be modified based on OAuth.

```
private Dictionary<string, MyTfsTeamProjectCollectionHelper> GetTFSProjectCollections()
{
    try
    {
        TFSConnectionProviderHelper connect = new TFSConnectionProviderHelper();
        ICredentials iCred = new NetworkCredential(strTFSUsername, strTFSPassword);
        connect.GetCredentials(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerURL"]), iCred);
        TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(new Uri(ServerURL), connect);
        configurationServer.EnsureAuthenticated();

        ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);
        DictionaryTfsTeamProjectCollection = new Dictionary<string, MyTfsTeamProjectCollectionHelper>();
        foreach (CatalogNode tpcNode in collectionNodes)
        {
            MyTfsTeamProjectCollectionHelper myTfsTeamProjectCollection = new MyTfsTeamProjectCollectionHelper();

            Guid tpcId = new Guid(tpcNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcId);
            myTfsTeamProjectCollection.TfsTeamProjectCollection = tfsTeamProjectCollection;

            DictionaryTfsTeamProjectCollection.Add(tfsTeamProjectCollection.Name.Replace(tfsTeamProjectCollection.ConfigurationServer.Name.ToString() + "/", "").ToLower(), myTfsTeamProjectCollection);
        }
        return DictionaryTfsTeamProjectCollection;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LogType.Error, strFlow, strCaseno, strTFSID, strUser, ex.Message);
        Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LogType.Error, strFlow, strCaseno, strTFSID, strUser, " StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }


}
private Project GetTFSProject(string tfsProjectCollectionName, string StrTFSProject)
{
    try
    {
        GetTFSProjectCollections();
        Project project = null;
        if (DictionaryTfsTeamProjectCollection != null && DictionaryTfsTeamProjectCollection.Keys.Contains(tfsProjectCollectionName.ToLower()))
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection myTeamProjectCollection = DictionaryTfsTeamProjectCollection[tfsProjectCollectionName.ToLower()].TfsTeamProjectCollection;
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = myTeamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            project = (from Project pr in workItemStore.Projects select pr).ToList().Where(i => i.Name.ToLower() == StrTFSProject.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LogType.Error, strFlow, strCaseno, strTFSID, StrTFSProjectcollection, "ProjectCollectionName does not exist:" + tfsProjectCollectionName);
        }
        return project;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LogType.Error, strFlow, strCaseno, strTFSID, strUser, ex.Message);
        Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LogType.Error, strFlow, strCaseno, strTFSID, strUser, " StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Screen shot of the permission page:

[image]

Ours is a `WebForms` Template. Is it possible to access **VSTS OAuth** through a simple **Asp.Net Webforms** template ?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t to do it without the permission authorize page and the user must accept or deny it manually. But it doesn’t need to authorize again if access token or refresh token (1 year expired) is valid.

There isn't the Asp.Net Webforms with VSTS OAuth template, but the workflows are the same whatever different types of web apps.

Comment: **There is the Asp.Net Webforms with VSTS OAuth template** - Is there a sample already? If so can you please point in the right direction.